# Eval function execution leads to internal error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am doing analysis of our application with IE Edge browser, while doing so I found a strange behaviour. Execution of eval function leads to the below error.
Even tried sample one like:

```
eval("2");
```

Error:
    SCRIPT51: Internal error

Please help me overcome this problem, in other browsers I am not facing this issue.

Comment: This seems to be a browser issue that is difficult to work around. And yet another reason for not using `eval` at all.

Comment: What do you need `eval` for?

Comment: @maja, I can't avoid using eval, our framework refers to eval at so many places.

Comment: I believe `eval("2")` is completely legit usage and there is no reason why  IE is throwing such error

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that this seems to be a browser issue of IE Edge.
You can't do anything to work around this issue except of getting rid of all your `eval` calls.

Since your application uses many `eval` functions (which is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86513/2224996)), getting rid of them might be not an option. You'll have to wait until Microsoft fixes it's browser.

However, as `eval` is still used by many webpages, I'm sure that the bug will get a high priority and might be fixed before official release.

Comment: Or it will just be shipped with the bug, and eval declared a bad idea. Microsoft Works. Nobody said bug-free.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be I found the root cause, the below trick solves my problem.

eval function needs to be specifically called with window context (though actually not requires)

Edge browser seems to be having some issue with context during evaluation.